# JavaScript change background color of input field in specified value

Tags: javascript, text, input, colors, background

I'm going to use JavaScript for changing color of input field in specified value. I've created it, but it doesn't work, the input field background color didn't changed.

```
[...] other fields
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="ha_tpc[]" id="ha_tpc" onkeyup="getWarning()" size="5" value="<?php $a=set_value('ha_tpc[0]'); echo $a; ?>"/></td>
[...] other fields
```

and here the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getWarning() {
        var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
            if (obj[i].name == "ha_tpc[]") {
                var hatpc = obj[i].value;
                if (hatpc != 5) {
                    document.bgColor = "#E74C3C";
                }; 
            }                   
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    function getWarning() {
        var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
            if (obj[i].name == "ha_tpc[]") {
                var hatpc = obj[i].value;
                if (hatpc != 5) {
                    document.bgColor = "#E74C3C";
                    obj[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
                }; 
            }                   
        } 
    }
```

```html
    
        <input type="text" name="ha_tpc[]" id="ha_tpc" onkeyup="getWarning()" size="5" />
```

```
  obj[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

You forgot to add it to input.